Quartz.net Scheduling and is auto Rescheduling job during starup
Here is my sample code. When I run this, I see 2 log messages one says "Scheduling job" and right after that another message "Rescheduling job". These messages are making me think I'm doing something wrong. Please help me understand why Rescheduling messages is printed.
The messages are printed by just having the nlog config in the project.
2024/05/01 00:05:31.574 info: QuartzSample.Program[0] Starting...
2024/05/01 00:05:31.606 dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1] Hosting starting
2024/05/01 00:05:32.008 dbug: Quartz.Simpl.TaskSchedulingThreadPool[0] TaskSchedulingThreadPool configured with max concurrency of 10 and TaskScheduler ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.
2024/05/01 00:05:32.036 info: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl[0] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2024/05/01 00:05:32.038 info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0] Quartz Scheduler created
2024/05/01 00:05:32.047 info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0] JobFactory set to: Quartz.Simpl.MicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory
2024/05/01 00:05:32.049 info: Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore[0] RAMJobStore initialized.
2024/05/01 00:05:32.051 info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0] Quartz Scheduler 3.8.1.0 - 'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED' initialized
2024/05/01 00:05:32.053 info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0] Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool', size: 10
2024/05/01 00:05:32.055 info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0] Using job store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore', supports persistence: False, clustered: False
2024/05/01 00:05:32.082|INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding 1 jobs, 1 triggers. |
2024/05/01 00:05:32.167|INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding job: DEFAULT.Combined Configuration Trigger |
2024/05/01 00:05:32.167|DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Scheduling job: DEFAULT.Combined Configuration Trigger with trigger: DEFAULT.Combined Configuration Trigger |
2024/05/01 00:05:32.200|DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Rescheduling job: DEFAULT.Combined Configuration Trigger with updated trigger: DEFAULT.Combined Configuration Trigger |
2024/05/01 00:05:32.219 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024/05/01 00:05:32.227 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Hosting environment: Development
2024/05/01 00:05:32.229 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Content root path: C:\Users\greatadventure\source\repos\LEarning\QuartzSample\QuartzSample\bin\Debug\net6.0
2024/05/01 00:05:32.231 dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2] Hosting started
2024/05/01 00:05:32.235 info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0] Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    var logger= host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogInformation("Starting...");
    await host.RunAsync();

}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(p =>
    {
        p.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        p.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeScopes = true;
            options.SingleLine = true;
            options.TimestampFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff ";
        });
    })
   .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
   {
       services.AddQuartz(q =>
       {
           q.ScheduleJob<HelloJob>(trigger => trigger
           .WithIdentity("Combined Configuration Trigger")
           .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenSecondDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60)))
           .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(100, IntervalUnit.Second))
           .WithDescription("my awesome trigger configured for a job with single call")
           );
       });

       services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
       {
           options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
       });
   });

}
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Greetings from HelloJob!");
}
}
